# Interface Arduino and MSSQL using Python

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm a newbie to Python. My task is to fetch serial port output (from Arduino), then push the output to the Microsoft SQL Database using Python.

My Arduino project is recording student attendance using fingerprint. Every time a student has scanned his fingerprint, the Arduino will generate output like this:

```
{'SID':1,'Date':2018/11/18,'Time':12:17:36}
{'SID':2,'Date':2018/11/18,'Time':12:28:02}
...
...
```

I would like to let Python code to fetch these outputs, and push it to Microsoft SQL Database. And I want to make it real-time, which means a output will be push to MSSQL every single time when students scanned their fingerprint. So I have a while loop like this in my Python:

```
import pyodbc
import serial
import time
import datetime
import ast
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=DESKTOP-H7KQUT1;"
                      "Database=SAOS1;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
arduino = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600, timeout=.1)


while True:

    data = arduino.readline()[:-2].decode("utf-8")

    if data!="":

        Atd_Date = ast.literal_eval(data)['Date']
        Atd_InTime = ast.literal_eval(data)['Time']
        SID = ast.literal_eval(data)['SID']
        tsql = "INSERT INTO attendance (Atd_Date, Atd_InTime, SID) VALUES (?,?,?);"
        with cursor.execute(tsql,Atd_Date,Atd_InTime,SID):
            print ('Successfuly Inserted!')
```

Unfortunately, it won't work as expected. I can't really fetch the output from serial and push it to MSSQL. I got this error as well:

> line 20, in 
>       Atd_Date = ast.literal_eval(data)['Date'] node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')

These two websites have the similar case with me, [1](https://muhd-lokman.weebly.com/projects) and [2](https://engineersportal.com/blog/2018/2/25/python-datalogger-reading-the-serial-output-from-arduino-to-analyze-data-using-pyserial). Am I doing in a correct way?

Comment: No answers, just suggestions. First, "can't make it work" means nothing. Learn to ask [smart questions](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Next, you can't do everything at once. FOCUS on one specific task. I suggest you focus on retrieving data from the finger print reader first. Until that works, it is pointless to try doing "something" with that information. Lastly, what you posted as an "error" does not look like an actual error - just an indication that you had an error on line 20. There should be an error message of some sort.

Comment: @SMor question updated